# Runtime Error 6 Overflow shown after second entry of number

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I encounter this error with my scanning program where it scans serial number and check the 5 digits from position 12 for running numbers. However, when the number in position 12 is a 9, it shows the runtime error. I am unsure what is causing this. I hope someone can help. Thank you. The error happens when I scan a number eg Z121564182690072 C, it will accept then input but when I scan a second input, Z121564182690073 C, it will show the error. I believe the problem is coming from around this code.

```
  Case -1 'Scanned UUT is 1 more than a number in the list
                    'if sample size is more than half of the lot size then skip checking
                    If (CLng(Me.lblRequiredQty.Caption) / CLng(Me.txtLotQty.Text)) < (2 / 3) Then

                        If CLng(Me.lblRequiredQty.Caption) > 10 Then

                            If i < Me.lstUnit.ListCount - 1 Then
                                If CLng(CLng(Mid(Me.lstUnit.List(i + 1), 12, 5)) - CLng(Mid(Me.lstUnit.List(i), 12, 5))) = 1 Then
                                    Me.lstUnit.Selected(i) = True
                                    A = MsgBox("This unit serial number is in sequence with " & _
                                        Me.lstUnit.List(i) & " and " & Me.lstUnit.List(i + 1) & "!", vbExclamation, "Error!!!")
```

Comment: You should include your full code of that Sub and tell which line the Error happens to be. From this partial code, I feel like there is a better way to achieve your goal with simpler logic. Also be clear if this is VBA (in office products) or Visual Studio (not likely here).

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for the reply. I can include the full code. I am running it with visual studio as thats the one i have right now. But i was told this was compiled with Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition. I can provide the full code.

Comment: I just found out that aside "9", character "R" in the 12th position also shows this error :(

Comment: @PatricK Thank you again for the response. I have added the entire sub code in. but from the code, I cant tell which is causing the error.

Comment: *sequence* and *i* are declared as integers. Change those to longs. e.g. `Dim i as long, sequence as long`

Comment: Hi @user11174618 thank you for the response! I have tried that and it still gave me the same error. :/

Comment: In addition to declaring the variables as `Long`, the number starting at position 12 is '90072' which `CInt` will fail to convert. Try using `CLng` instead.

Comment: Integer (2^16) in VBA/VB6 is signed and is from -32k to +32k. A long (2^32) is -2 billion to +2 billion.

Comment: Hi @KellyEthridge i tried this too but it also does not work :/

Comment: Hi All, thank you for the help. I believe the issue been narrow down to the above problem.